# Multi theme setup - webpack / Vue-cli

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader, vue-cli-3

I'm about to create embeddable application that can be styled per client on a basic level (colors mostly).

My idea was to use some query parameters of an embed, like here: `<iframe src="embeddedApplication?theme=client_1"/>` and then read query parameter and request appropriate styling on top of the base. All good, easy peasy lemon squeezy.

What i didn't foresee is that webpack configuration is gonna be such a pain in the sass. I'm used to vue-cli and i'd rather stick to it (that probably means webpack-chain, but thats not an issue) at least would like to keep it's webpack config and just extend it.

Ideally i'd like to create `client_1.scss` and `client_2.scss` and so on containig only scss variables. Then i'd (ideally) talk webpack somehow into looping through all `.vue` files (as it normally does) but then repeat the loop for every `client_N.scss` file, resolving settings import from this file.

Visually:

```
src
|--themes
|  |-- client_1.scss
|  |-- client_2.scss
|
|--components
   |-- comp_A
   |-- comp_B

dist
|--client_1.css /* comp_A + comp_B with variables from client_1.scss
|--client_1.css /* comp_A + comp_B with variables from client_2.scss
```

I've tried a lot, but i didn't manage to come close to this. Closest i've got was generating two separate styles (adding `*.scss` entry points). But then I'm just writing global styles.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

#### UPDATE

Currently i'm loading multiple JSON files containing scss variables (sounds kinda funny, i know; that's the way of `@epegzz/sass-vars-loader`) so the scss variables are resolved correctly in vue single file components.

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync('./src/assets/themes/');

    files.forEach(file => {
        config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue')
            .use('sass-vars-loader')
            .loader('@epegzz/sass-vars-loader')
            .options({
                syntax: 'scss',
                files: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, `src/assets/themes/${file}`)
                ]
            })
    });
}
```

That's all nice but the original problem is actually unresolved. My forEach loop does include all the files, but there's still *only one css output*.

If i could only 'repeat' the whole build process again...?